# Could not load state specified by InResponseTo: NOSTATE Processing response as unsolicited

Tags: simplesamlphp

After upgrading to php7.3 I'm having issues with authenticating.
I am being redirected to the correct page to autenthicate, after succesfully loging in (I do recieve the correct response in logs) I'm falling into a redirect loop.

Is this a general thing? Or do I need to provide more details about setup?

used versions:
php7.3
simpleSAMLphp 1.18.4
(in combination with custom wordpress page)

Answer (score 4):

Making these changes in config/config.php fixed the issue. Also ensure that all the URLs specified in config files are HTTPS.

```
'session.cookie.secure' => true,
'session.cookie.domain' => '.example.org',
'session.cookie.samesite' => 'None',
```